# Current-mode buck: get current from inductor winding

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, current-measurement, buck, control-system

I was recently reading about current-mode control in switching converters.

When discussing the current sense signal, all sources I have read either show the current sense as some kind of additional current transformer (or Hall based current-meter), e.g. [here](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/modeling-and-control-for-current-mode-buck-converter-with-a-secondary-lc-filter.html):

[image]

Or they show a small sense resistor with a difference amplifier, e.g. [here](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/peak-current-mode-and-continuous-current-mode-dc-dc-converters.html):

[image]

I was wondering if the current-signal could be fed back into the modulator directly by using another winding over the main power choke, which sounds essentially *"too easy"*, so I simulated it:

[image]

To my surprise, this seems to actually work in spice. In that sim, the converter runs at about 1 MHz and loses well below 1 % of power in the current feedback. Is this known to fail in practical designs? If so, what is the issue in a practical implementation?

Comment: Designers prefer to use an external \$RC\$ circuit placed across the inductor: if the time constants are equal \$RC=\frac{L}{r_L}\$ then you can collect the inductor current \$i_L(t)\$ without other sensing solutions. See [here](https://www.richtek.com/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN037) for more details.

Comment: @VerbalKint It is an interesting technique, but rather different from my question if I understand correctly. With respect to this question, would that inductor winding likely work? It also extends rather neatly to a multiphase converter because the sense windings could all be paralleled into the modulator summing node.

Comment: Why do you think this is an easy solution? In my book this requires using a custom inductor/current transformer instead of a cheap inductor and for example the on-resistance of the power MOSFET that is required anyway.

Comment: @LarsHankeln For a one-off design, I agree.  But for high quantity stuff, that transformer winding is rather easily implemented..For me this is curiosity at the moment. What do you mean about the FET resistance. How does its importance differ between this design and any other one ?

Comment: FET on-resistance can be used for current sensing instead of an additional current sense resistor is what I meant. This is also relatively common afaik.

Comment: In what way does a separate winding capture the DC current flowing through the primary? Sweep the load: I think you will find you've made a voltage-mode modulator instead.

Comment: @TimWilliams If I understand current-mode control correctly, it is not about the DC current through the inductor but using its ripple as a slope for the PWM generation..But I am not sure about it. But you seem to be right anyway: removing the inductor has similar transient performance (just at lower frequency), because the inductor doesnt actually provide a current signal

Comment: It's both. A current mode control literally limits inductor current (and therefore input or output current) to the set value. If it's tracking AC, you might get the dynamics, but that's equivalent to ESR on the output cap in a voltage-mode control (VMC) -- granted, maybe without the losses, so, suppose we used a small ESR and amplified its voltage drop for control purposes (good luck IRL, but we can do that trivially in simulation). But the VMC still exhibits unbounded switch/inductor current.

Comment: Note that transformers aren't completely inapplicable: a current feedback signal can be reconstructed by putting a CT on each switch/diode, using a diode to OR their currents into a common burden resistor. The two paths must be used, since they each return to zero (allowing the CT flux to reset), whereas the inductor has continuous current so only the ripple can be sensed by CT (equivalent to the ESR case).